# cmd execution in delphi without freezing

Tags: delphi, cmd

I have been trying to execute some cmd dos commands within Delphi project with the help of cmd execution function which works well but when the execution is in process the application seems to be like freeze and like blocked till the process is over .. I need help is there any tricks to bypass the process so the application behave normal when execution is in process .

**Update from comments:**

the function which i am using creates pipe:

```
if CreatePipe(read_stdout, newstdout, @sa, 0) then begin 
  GetStartupInfo(si); 
  with si do begin 
    dwFlags := STARTF_USESTDHANDLES or STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW; 
    wShowWindow := SW_HIDE; 
    hStdOutput := newstdout; 
    hStdError := newstdout; 
    hStdInput := newstdin; 
  end;
```

After Google I found a Function here http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Pascal/Delphi/Q_25050763.html

Approach 1: (Author: Marco Pipino) ......

Can anybody help me to modify this function so that enduser not think the application is hanging while performing the command?

Comment: Please add in the code/exception otherwise people won't be able to help you.

Comment: [Communicate With Command Prompt Through Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598313/communicate-with-command-prompt-through-delphi) and 
[Get non blocking CommandLine output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443037/get-non-blocking-commandline-output)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are blocking the main thread. The main thread of an application must process messages in a timely fashion in order to remain responsive.

The right way to tackle this is to start the external process, and then wait for it, from a thread. Doing this ensures that you don't block the main thread. You may well wish to use some inter thread communication to provide user feedback.

Comment: It will be better for you to put the effort in to learn about this rather than have somebody write it all for you. Remember also that you showed no code and gave no indication of the version of Delphi. In XE7 you might use the new high level parallel library.

Comment: I use D7 and the function  I use to capture output is [function ExecuteCommand(CommandLine: string): string;] which I found from http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Pascal/Delphi/Q_25050763.html but when the commands are performed .. application remains like hang till the commands ends .. how can I get rid from this

Comment: Deal with the issue the way I said. Use a thread to avoid blocking the main thread. I can see you are new here so some advice. Don't post code as links. Especially not links to code behind pay walls. All the same we don't really need code here. You need to understand how the UI thread works and the fact that you must not block it.

Answer (score -2):

As a quick-fix, I'd `START` the batch, then have it signal completion by creating or deleting a file, eg:

```
@echo off
setlocal
echo.>"c:\some\filename"
start "title if you want one" yourrealbatch anditsparameters
```

`yourrealbatch` should then delete `"c:\some\filename"` after its finished processing

Then have delphi simply monitor the presence of `"c:\some\filename"`. When it disappears, the batch process is complete.

Comment: I don't use batch in Delphi.. I use function to capture dos output in Memo with the function function GetDosOutput(CommandLine: string; Work: string = 'C:\'): string; my problem is when command is in process the Delphi application remain unresponsive or like freeze till the command execution is over .. I am looking alternate so that when command execution process the application [Form] should not freeze . should be moveable not like unresponsive...

Comment: the function which i am using creates pipe  if CreatePipe(read_stdout, newstdout, @sa, 0) then
    begin
      GetStartupInfo(si);
      with si do
      begin
        dwFlags := STARTF_USESTDHANDLES or STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
        wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;

        hStdOutput := newstdout;
        hStdError := newstdout;
        hStdInput := newstdin;
      end;

Comment: After Google I found a Function here http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Pascal/Delphi/Q_25050763.html ....  Approach 1:   (Author:      Marco Pipino) ......  can anybody help me to modify this function so that enduser not think the application is hanging while performing the command.

Comment: Magoo, even if this were a legitimate solution, it still doesn't solve the problem of the main thread being blocked. You would still have to "watch" this file in a loop, which would still block the main thread.

Comment: @JerryDodge: A cardinal error on your part! As posted, the question was tagged only `cmd` with none of the additional detail now provided with ex-site references. From the original question the problem was a `cmd` procedure taking control. This would most certainly have worked had that been the case.This solution returns control to the main thread to do whatever it wants, servicing any events it wants. If the programmer requires that the "blocking" procedure completes before continuing, then the main may not proceed until the blocking procedure completes, regardless.